# Android - Java: How to reproduce audio through A2DP speaker (bluetooth) using Audiotrack

Tags: android, bluetooth, audiotrack, a2dp

I just need to reproduce a song for example through A2DP speaker (blueetooth) using Audiotrack just like Youtube App does it when you pair your cellphone with your stereo.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By reproduce, do you mean play the music over Blueooth A2DP ?

Comment: @Mackovich Yes, I need to play audio through bluetooth speaker (over a2dp) using Audiotrack, thanks for the quick response :)

Comment: Alright. First, are you already connected to your A2DP Bluetooth Speaker ? If yes, just user a MediaPlayer, Android will automatically stream to your speaker for as long it remains connected. But if you need to connect, do you want to do it in code (from your app) ?